# Export to excel from Object

Tags: excel, vb.net, function, export

I'm trying to export a query to excel, i got the query and then i save the result in:

```
 Dim _Result As Object = Nothing
```

**_Result** is declare as  a Object.
In the next code the query is saved into **_Result**

```
        _Result = _Query.GetRecords(_pOP, _
                                       _pName, _
                                       _pLastName, _
                                       _pAdress, _
                                       _pEFSL, _
                                       )
```

In this point everything runs fine, but i would like to know how to covert that result in a XLS file.

**nQuerys** is a Class that have the procedures to retrieve information from the DB., the function **GetRecords (function into nQuerys)** retuns the info in a **List** and then AJAX_Directory 
receives the information after the info is stored in **_Result**, thanks for your answer.

Here is my code complete. Thanks you for your help.

```
<WebMethod>
Public Shared Function AJAX_Directory(_pOP, _
                                       _pName, _
                                       _pLastName, _
                                       _pAdress, _
                                       _pEFSL, _
                                       ) As Object

    Dim _Query As New nQuerys   <--------- This is a class where I have all my procedures that retrieve information from the database
    Dim _Result As Object = Nothing

    Try

        _Result = _Query.GetRecords(_pOP, _
                                       _pName, _
                                       _pLastName, _
                                       _pAdress, _
                                       _pEFSL, _
                                      )

        Return _Result 

    Catch ex As Exception
        Return ex.Message
    Finally
        _Query = Nothing
    End Try

End Function
```

Comment: What is nQuerys?

Comment: Is a class where I have all my procedures that retrieve information from the database, i have posted more information, thanks for your answer